# Xcode - Create new C++ File - Order .h and .cpp - Order in Project Navigator

Tags: c++, xcode

When creating a new Cocoa Class Xcode puts the .h file above the .m file in the project navigator.

For C++ Classes it's the opposite.

Why is this and how can I change this default behaviour?

Comment: It's because they're ordered alphabetically, h comes before m but after c.

Comment: Indeed; one approach is to separate the header and implementation files into different groups, if it bothers you that much.  They can remain in the same directory in the filesytem regardless of the file group in Xcode.

Comment: I don't want groups, I just want the .h file to be above the .cpp file whenver I create a new file.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving it with your mouse. As long as you have latest XCode - it should allow you to do that. You can even move files to different "folders" to organize them.

Comment: I know I can do it by hand, but I don't want to. I want to change the default behaviour.